# Installing Ruby 1.8.7-p374 and Rails 3.2.13 error in rack-cache

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

How can I installing Rails 3.2.13 in a Ruby 1.8.7?

My hosting server using these versions and I would like to set up a environment in Vagrant using a CentOS 7 box.

I install a Ruby 1.8.7 using a RVM.

When I trying to install the Rails 3.2.13, I received an error message: `(rack-cache need ruby >= 2.0.0)`

Any idea how can I install Rails 3.2.13 using Ruby 1.8.7 ?

```
[vagrant@ror02 ~]$ ruby -v
ruby 1.8.7 (2013-06-27 patchlevel 374) [x86_64-linux]
[vagrant@ror02 ~]$ gem install rails -v 3.2.13
Fetching: i18n-0.6.1.gem (100%)
Successfully installed i18n-0.6.1
Fetching: multi_json-1.13.1.gem (100%)
Successfully installed multi_json-1.13.1
Fetching: activesupport-3.2.13.gem (100%)
Successfully installed activesupport-3.2.13
Fetching: builder-3.0.4.gem (100%)
Successfully installed builder-3.0.4
Fetching: activemodel-3.2.13.gem (100%)
Successfully installed activemodel-3.2.13
Fetching: rack-1.4.7.gem (100%)
Successfully installed rack-1.4.7
Fetching: rack-cache-1.8.0.gem (100%)
ERROR:  Error installing rails:
rack-cache requires Ruby version >= 2.0.0.
[vagrant@ror02 ~]$
```

Comment: **Why** do you feel the need to install an ancient version of rails, with an even more ancient version of ruby? And the short answer is that no, you can't; these versions are incompatible, as the error message states.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you have rvm you may just install the latest ruby and rails. There is no need to use the system wide installed version.

https://rvm.io/gemsets/basics

I just use ruby 2.5.1 and rails 5.2.0.